# Expressing a property of a function in terms of its derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Assume function $f$ has the following property: $$f(x+h,y-h) - f(x,y) > 0$$ for any $h \leq y$. What is the equivalent representation of this property in terms of the (partial) derivatives of the function $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Taylor expansion for $f(x+h, y-h)$ gives $$f(x+h, y-h) = f(x,y) + h\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - h \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \mathcal{O}(h^2),$$ so your condition becomes $$ (\partial_x f - \partial_y f) + \mathcal{O}(h) >0.$$ Taking $h \to 0$ we deduce that $$\partial_x f > \partial_y f.$$

Conversely, if $\partial_x f > \partial_y f$ then for $h$ small enough $$\frac{f(x+h,y) - f(x,y)}{h} > \frac{f(x,y+h) - f(x,y)}{h},$$ i.e. $$f(x+h,y) - f(x,y+h) > 0.$$ Write $\tilde{y} = y+h$, then $y=\tilde{y} -h$ and you're done.